# Weird watermark image in android app

Tags: android, android-resources, watermark

After uploading a new apk to the Play Store, we are noticing a weird watermark appearing on the home screen of the app which looks like the image below.

[image: watermark]

The actual background image that should be seen is missing. This issue is affecting a few users and it goes away when they delete and reinstall the app from the Play Store.

What could be a possible cause for this?

Comment: That doesn't look like a watermark image.  It looks like the asset that should be your background is being replaced by an image of a close button.

Comment: You should check that your background drawable is the right one in each drawable-xxx folder, or make sure that you use the correct resource id, or make sure that you do not use a android.R.drawable that may change across devices.

Comment: @DeeV How can that happen though? Did the Resource id's get messed up during the update. Can that happen?

Comment: @Pdroid We only have one set of background image assets so they're all in the drawalble-nodpi folder

Comment: @tbag: This can happen if the IDs in the R-file don't get updated when installing a new app.  I would hope that an app update wouldn't cause this issue (which means it's a bug on Google's side and not yours).  This can also happen if you have different resources of the same name that are in different drawable folders. You may try a full clean and build, then re-upload to the play store in case the APK is somehow corrupted. I'm not sure what would cause the issue otherwise.

Comment: @Deev Did a full clean and build and submitted an update. But the issue still exists.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes we were using the resource id instead of asset name in some places causing this bug